# What is the easiest way to turn a string with whitespaces camelcase in java?

Tags: java

Input string: "Transaction 1data is2 ent3ered"

Expected output: "Transaction1dataIs2Ent3ered"

please include your code sample, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a homework problem for school.

Comment: When asking about homework problems, you are supposed to show the work you've done already, and ask about rather specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.  But often the first character is normally lower case.

```
String text = "Transaction 1data is2 ent3ered";
String camelText = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s+"))
        .map(wd -> Character.toUpperCase(wd.charAt(0))
                + wd.substring(1))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(camelText);
```

Prints

```
Transaction1dataIs2Ent3ered
```

Comment: perfect! thanks for the answer and the prints!

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
    .map(word -> word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another way. There are more...

```
String result = Pattern.compile("\\s.")
            .matcher("Transaction 1data is2 ent3ered")
            .replaceAll(m -> m.group().substring(1).toUpperCase());
```